# How to call an express export method internally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongoose

This is my first method that responds well to an http call:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next){
  var submission = new task(req.body);  

   submission.save(function(err){
     if(err){
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.json(submission);
    }
  });

};
```

Now, I want to call this from a method defined in the same file:

```
exports.evaluate = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.body.value == x){
    // need to call the above method
   this.create(req.body.someobject)
  }
};
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to define a common method which isn't a route handler and call it from the handlers.

```
var _create = function (object, callback) {
  var submission = new task (object);
  submission.save(callback);
}

exports.create = function(req, res, next){
  _create(req.body, function(err){
     if(err){
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.json(submission);
    }
  });
};

exports.evaluate = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.body.value == x){
    // need to call the above method
    _create(req.body.someobject, function (err) {
      // Send response
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Calling `create(req, res, next)` from evaluate isn't impossible by declaring the `create` explicitly, its wise to separate the code for different request handlers.

In this case, it looks more like the handlers can be parameterized and merged into one single function.